# In Rust, possible to downcast a trait to an owned type?

Tags: rust, lifetime

In Rust, I'm able to downcast a trait object to a concrete type using .as_any().downcast_ref(). That works ok, but it returns a &ref, not the owned object itself.

How can I get ownership of a downcast object?

**Update:**
In response to the comments, here is what I was trying to do:

```
trait Foo {
    fn hello() -> String;
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar {
    fn hello() -> String {
        "hello".to_owned()
    }

    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}

fn some_func(foo: impl Foo) {
    // I want a Bar here, not a &Bar
    let bar_opt = foo.as_any().downcast_ref::<Bar>();
}
```

I can see why .as_any() would not work, because it returns a reference.

Comment: What owns the trait object before downcasting? i.e. Box vs Rc vs Arc What would the type signature of your function ideally be?

Comment: `Any` has a [`downcast`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html#method.downcast) method, as long as the source is a `Box<dyn Any>`, [or Rc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downcast), [or Arc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.downcast).

Comment: You mean of your own trait, or of `std`'s `Any`?

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved using Box and the downcast() method, which consumes the boxed trait object and returns a 'Result' containing either the downcasted object or an error if the types don't match. I would need your specific code to provide an implementation for your situation, but here's an example of its use:

```
use std::any::Any;

let animal: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new("Dog");
if let Ok(dog) = animal.downcast::<String>() {
    println!("It's a dog named {}", dog);
} else {
    println!("Not a dog");
}
```

Thw code tries to downcast a trait object 'animal' to a String, allowing us to use String methods if successful

Comment: "Not a String" seems more accurate? I think talking about Dog makes the example less clear.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I can give a different example if you'd like. OP didn't give me anything to work on.